# jquery ajax: how to keep record not dissapear when the page is refresh

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

i use this script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $(".comment_button").click(function () {
      var element = $(this);
      var boxval = $("#content").val();
      var dataString = 'content=' + boxval;
      if (boxval == '') {
        alert("Please Enter Some Text");
      } else {
        $("#flash").show();
        $("#flash").fadeIn(400).html('<img src="ajax.gif" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;<span class="loading">Loading Update...</span>');
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "update_data.php",
          data: dataString,
          cache: false,
          success: function (html) {

            $("ol#update").prepend(html);
            $("ol#update li:first").slideDown("slow");
            document.getElementById('content').value = '';
            $("#flash").hide();
          }
        });
      }
      return false;
    });
    $('.delete_update').live("click", function () {
      var ID = $(this).attr("id");
      var dataString = 'msg_id=' + ID;
      if (confirm("Sure you want to delete this update? There is NO undo!")) {
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "delete_data.php",
          data: dataString,
          cache: false,
          success: function (html) {
            $(".bar" + ID).slideUp('slow', function () {
              $(this).remove();
            });
          }
        });
      }
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

this script combine live update and delete record using jquery and ajax

the problem is when I refresh the page, the record will disappear .. how to keep records that show up are not dissapear when the page is reloaded?

Answer (score 0):

First Check the comment list. Did you put any limit in query, if so then use Order by Primary ID desc.So it would display latest records first.

When you delete any record, check whether it is actually deleted from database or not. Because you are not checking whether record actually deleted or not as per the code you given.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using update_data.php and delete_data.php to manipulate some database, you could use PHP to render the page initially using the data that is currently on the database.

If that is not the case, and you don't have access to that database (it could be a third party web service, right?), or you don't want to do that for any reason, you could use cookie like Saeed answered.